# Did my hydraulic separator's valve fail due to low operating temperature?

Tags: vent

Three years ago I purchased a Hydraulic Separator that came with a High Pressure Vent on top. The components were of a common name brand, yet in only 3 years the Vent failed in an odd way. At normal operating conditions, sub 25psi and 160 degrees Fahrenheit, it works fine. However this year when boiler went dormant, as heaters do in the summer, the valve started leaking quite a bit.

Reviewing the specs of the replacement (same part, not broken) I see it has a "minimum temp: 140". So, is it odd that this part failed after only 3 years, or is it normal to maintain a minimum temperature for some plumbing components?